# Generics with constraints

Tags: f#

```
type VBO<'T when 'T : (new : unit -> 'T) and 'T : struct and 'T :> ValueType> = 
...

type VAO =
    static member Create(vboList : VBO<'T> list) = 
...
```

Now when I do

```
val a : VBO<Vector3>
val b : VBO<float>

VAO.Create([a;b])// F# forces vboList to be of type VBO<Vector3> list
```

I just want my vboList to treat every type the same as long as they fulfill the following constraint `<'T when 'T : (new : unit -> 'T) and 'T : struct and 'T :> ValueType>`

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to create a base parameterless type and use that as the elements of your list:

```
type VBO_Base =
    class end

type VBO<'T when 'T : (new : unit -> 'T) and 'T : struct and 'T :> ValueType> = 
    inherit VBO_Base
    ...

type VAO =
    static member Create(vboList : VBO_Base list) = 
    ...

val a : VBO<Vector3>
val b : VBO<float>

VAO.Create([a;b]) // both a and be get automatically downcast to VBO_Base
```

And in fact you can call this base type `VBO`, since .NET allows two different types to have the same name if they have a different number of parameters.

Comment: I don't think that this can work. When I upcast my VBO to VBO_BASE I lose every information about my data, and lose the ability to downcast the VBO_BASE because I don't know what type it was. I think the solution would be to implement a common interface for float, float32, vector3 etc, but I am not sure how I would do it.

Comment: You can have abstract methods in `VBO_Base`, which each `VBO<'T>` overrides appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `a` and `b` have different types.

Lists can only contain elements of a single type.

For example `[a;a]` is fine as is `[b;b]` but `[a;b]` is not.

One way around this would be to make a new class heirachy were you have a new `float` and `Vector3` that both inherit from the same base class and you could downcast the objects to that type.

Comment: How would I create a base for a float? Or would it be possible to erase the type completely?